# 'System.Data.DataRow.DataRow(System.Data.DataRowBuilder)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to add a new word from a textbox into a table:

```
private void addAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get a new row from the data table
    myDataTable.NewRow();
    DataRow Row1 = new DataRow();
    Row1["Word"] = QuizAnswer.Text;
    myDataTable.Rows.Add(Row1);

    // Locate the newly added row
    currentRecord = myDataTable.Rows.IndexOf(Row1);
    DisplayRow(currentRecord);

    // Commit changes to the database
    UpdateDB();
    myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
}
```

However it is giving me this strange error:

> Error 1   'System.Data.DataRow.DataRow(System.Data.DataRowBuilder)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, you cannot create a `new DataRow()` yourself.

Instead, you need to call `table.NewRow()`, and use the returned row.

Comment: I was attempting to add a new record based on the user input in the textbox with the code above, however when I do `DataRow newRow = QuizAnswer.Text;` it obviously doesn't like the string.

Comment: You need to create a row using `table.NewRow()`, then assign values to its columns.

Comment: @SLaks I tried your suggested way but I am getting error that says A column named 'CODE' already belongs to this DataTable. why to getting that error since i what I am doing is add new item to bounded combobox ??

Comment: @sam: That has nothing to do with any of this.  What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: @SLaks why I am getting Error  `A column named 'CODE' already belongs to this DataTable` while I know that and what I am trying to do is add new item to already existing `combobox`? 
example... my `combobox` has several values, but in special case I need to add a additional value to this `combobox`

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a new DataRow as such:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
```